# Get Memory Size With INT 12

Tags: memory, kernel, nasm, interrupt

I want to get memory size in assembly with int 12, but when I call this interrupt it only gives 639. What does 639 mean? (I converted from integer to String)

Ex:

```
  bits 16
  org 0x0

  start:
  int 12h;GET MEMORY TO AX (KB)
  mov bx,ax ;BX=AX
  call int_to_str ;IN:BX(INT)-OUT:BX(STRING)
  mov si,bx  ;SI=BX
  call print_string  ;PRINT SI
  mov ax,10h  ;KEY STROKE
  int 16h
  ret
```

This code gives only 639. I didn't understand yet. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INT 12h only reports first 640KB of memory. Your program occupied one 1KB block, hence it returned 639. Getting available memory is a little bit tricky. For details see [here](http://vitaly_filatov.tripod.com/ng/asm/asm_001.10.html).

Comment: In the link provided in my answer ([http://vitaly_filatov.tripod.com/ng/asm/asm_001.10.html](http://vitaly_filatov.tripod.com/ng/asm/asm_001.10.html)) there is exact procedure outlined. Please look into it.